# Sort All the Information by Date DJANGO

Tags: python, django, web-applications, backend

I have a model named "Thing" as in the HelloWebApp book. Now I've added a "weight" model. The model has fields "date" and "weight_value". While displaying the data in "thing_detail.html" I want to display the data ordered by the field "date".

Here are my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Thing(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, blank=True, null=True)

class Weight(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    weight_value = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    thingRA = models.ForeignKey(Thing,related_name="weights")

    class Meta:
        order_with_respect_to = 'thingRA'
```

and thing_details.html

```
{% extends 'layouts/base.html' %}
{% block title %}
{{ thing.name }} - {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div id="content">
<!-- Below is to check if the data belongs to the original user -->
{% if user == thing.user %}
<h1>{{ thing.name }}</h1>
<p>{{ thing.description }}</p><br>
{% if weights %}
    {% for weightshow in weights %}
        <p>>Weight as on {{weightshow.date}} : {{weightshow.weight_value}}</p>
    {% empty %}
        <p>Sorry! You haven't logged any weight records yet</p>
   {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
<br><br>
<a href="{% url 'edit_thing' slug=thing.slug %}"><u>Edit Me!</u></a>
<br>
<a href="{% url 'edit_weight' slug=thing.slug %}"><u>Log Weight Record!</u></a>
</div>
{% else %}
<h1>Error!</h1>
<p>You do not have the permission to view this account. If this is your account please logout and login to <strong>{{thing.name}}</strong></p><br>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Kindly someone help!

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks For the Edit @kartikmaji

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your Weight model

```
class Meta:
    ordering = ['date']
```

Or when you are making query add order_by(). Like,

```
Weight.objects.all().order_by('date')
```

Comment: Thanks! Works Perfect.